# Return a string from generic handler

Tags: c#, angularjs, generics

I want to return a string from generic handler and get it into angularjs. My code is below.
Generic handler:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    List<string>  path= new List<string>();
    if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
            string fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/upload/" + file.FileName);
            //file.SaveAs(fname);
            path.Add(fname);
        }
    }
    string abc = path[0].ToString();
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write(abc);
}
```

Angularjs Controller:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function () {
    var fd = new FormData()
    for (var i in ScopGloble.files) {
       // alert("hi I am in");
        fd.append("uploadedFile", $scope.files[i])
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("POST", "FileuploadTask.ashx")
    ScopGloble.progressVisible = true
    xhr.send(fd)
    //How I can get file path here.
}
```

How I can get file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the XHR object's `responseText`.

However, you can't get it where you have the comment, since XMLHttpRequest is typically asynchronous. You'd need something like

```
//before we send the request
xhr.onload = function(xhrEventArgs) {
  var ThePath = xhr.responseText;
  //do something with that string
};
//now, send the request
xhr.send(fd);
```

You should probably check the request status in there too. See the [MDN XHR documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) for more info on that.